# How to convert SparkR DataFrame to RDD

Tags: r, rdd, sparkr

I know how to convert a text file into an RDD with SparkR:

```
data <- textFile(sc, "data/tsv_wiki")
```

But I would want to know how to convert an object of type DataFrame in R to an RDD.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps ampcamp should provide this link in their exercise: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html.

Comment: I'm not asking this for an ampcamp exercise. I haven't been able to find how to convert a DataFrame to an RDD in the SparkR (1.6) API (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/R/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @r2evans, but that link is just a general overview of SparkR that doesn't even mention RDD... I'm trying to perform this conversion not as part of any online course exercise, but as a way to perform certain dplyr-style operations directly over the RDD (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657974/sparkr-dplyr-style-split-apply-combine-on-dataframe)

Comment: Sorry, I'm (obviously) not a Spark guru. I was inferring from the docs that since they renamed [SchemaRDD to DataFrame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#rename-of-schemardd-to-dataframe) and talk about [converting DataFrames from local data frames](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#from-local-data-frames), it was all equivalent. (I'm almost certainly confused, which may be understandable with all the *Data*s and *Frame*s going around :-)

Comment: Don't worry :-), I'm also confused. I knew that you can use the `.rdd` method to convert a DataFrame to an RDD. Unfortunately, that method doesn't exist in SparkR from an existing RDD (just when you load a text file, as in the example), which makes me wonder why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It couldn't be easier.

```
converted.rdd <- SparkR:::toRDD(dataframe)
```

Note the triple colon operator, meaning that it's an internal function.