# Spark SQL: apply aggregate functions to a list of columns

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions

Is there a way to apply an aggregate function to all (or a list of) columns of a dataframe, when doing a `groupBy`? In other words, is there a way to avoid doing this for every column:

```py
df.groupBy("col1")
  .agg(sum("col2").alias("col2"), sum("col3").alias("col3"), ...)
```

Answer (score 175, accepted):

There are multiple ways of applying aggregate functions to multiple columns.

`GroupedData` class provides a number of methods for the most common functions, including `count`, `max`, `min`, `mean` and `sum`, which can be used directly as follows:

- Python:

  ```py
  df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
      [(1.0, 0.3, 1.0), (1.0, 0.5, 0.0), (-1.0, 0.6, 0.5), (-1.0, 5.6, 0.2)],
      ("col1", "col2", "col3"))

  df.groupBy("col1").sum()

  ## +----+---------+-----------------+---------+
  ## |col1|sum(col1)|        sum(col2)|sum(col3)|
  ## +----+---------+-----------------+---------+
  ## | 1.0|      2.0|              0.8|      1.0|
  ## |-1.0|     -2.0|6.199999999999999|      0.7|
  ## +----+---------+-----------------+---------+
  ```
- Scala

  ```scala
  val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (1.0, 0.3, 1.0), (1.0, 0.5, 0.0),
    (-1.0, 0.6, 0.5), (-1.0, 5.6, 0.2))
  ).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")

  df.groupBy($"col1").min().show

  // +----+---------+---------+---------+
  // |col1|min(col1)|min(col2)|min(col3)|
  // +----+---------+---------+---------+
  // | 1.0|      1.0|      0.3|      0.0|
  // |-1.0|     -1.0|      0.6|      0.2|
  // +----+---------+---------+---------+
  ```

Optionally you can pass a list of columns which should be aggregated

```
df.groupBy("col1").sum("col2", "col3")
```

You can also pass dictionary / map with columns a the keys and functions as the values:

- Python

  ```py
  exprs = {x: "sum" for x in df.columns}
  df.groupBy("col1").agg(exprs).show()

  ## +----+---------+
  ## |col1|avg(col3)|
  ## +----+---------+
  ## | 1.0|      0.5|
  ## |-1.0|     0.35|
  ## +----+---------+
  ```
- Scala

  ```scala
  val exprs = df.columns.map((_ -> "mean")).toMap
  df.groupBy($"col1").agg(exprs).show()

  // +----+---------+------------------+---------+
  // |col1|avg(col1)|         avg(col2)|avg(col3)|
  // +----+---------+------------------+---------+
  // | 1.0|      1.0|               0.4|      0.5|
  // |-1.0|     -1.0|3.0999999999999996|     0.35|
  // +----+---------+------------------+---------+
  ```

Finally you can use varargs:

- Python

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql.functions import min

  exprs = [min(x) for x in df.columns]
  df.groupBy("col1").agg(*exprs).show()
  ```
- Scala

  ```scala
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum

  val exprs = df.columns.map(sum(_))
  df.groupBy($"col1").agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*)
  ```

There are some other way to achieve a similar effect but these should more than enough most of the time.

See also:

- [Multiple Aggregate operations on the same column of a spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34954771/10465355)

Comment: It seems  `aggregateBy` would be applicable here. It is faster (to much faster) than `groupBy`. Oh wait - the `DataFrame` does not expose `aggregateBy` -- `agg` is pointed to `groupBy`.  Well that means `DataFrames` are *slow* ..

Comment: @javadba No, it only means that `Dataset.groupBy` /  `Dataset.groupByKey` and `RDD.groupBy` / `RDD.groupByKey`  have, in general case, different semantics. In case of simple `DataFrame` aggregations [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32903568/1560062). There is more to that, but it is not important here.

Comment: @javadba Thanks. Here is another useful (subjectively, self-promotion alert) resource: https://git.io/vM1Ch

Comment: How to add alias to the columns ?

Comment: @GeekFactory `exprs = [min(x).alias("{0}".format(x)) for x in df.columns]`

Comment: A straightforward solution to aliasing is to set new column names after groupBy, e.g.: `X = df.columns[1:]; new_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']; exprs = {x: "sum" for x in X}; dg = df.groupBy("col1").agg(exprs); dg = dg.toDF(*new_cols)`

Comment: @zero323 .. nice one.

Comment: @zero323 great answer. what would it be if I'd like to compute multiple stats for each column. Would it be **exprs = [ [min(x).alias("{0}_min".format(x)), max(x).alias("{0}_max".format(x)), mean(x).alias("{0}_mean".format(x)) ] for x in df.columns]**

Answer (score 27):

Another example of the same concept - but say - you have 2 different columns - and you want to apply different agg functions to each of them i.e

```
f.groupBy("col1").agg(sum("col2").alias("col2"), avg("col3").alias("col3"), ...)
```

Here is the way to achieve it - though I do not yet know how to add the alias in this case

See the example below - Using Maps

```scala
val Claim1 = StructType(Seq(StructField("pid", StringType, true),StructField("diag1", StringType, true),StructField("diag2", StringType, true), StructField("allowed", IntegerType, true), StructField("allowed1", IntegerType, true)))
val claimsData1 = Seq(("PID1", "diag1", "diag2", 100, 200), ("PID1", "diag2", "diag3", 300, 600), ("PID1", "diag1", "diag5", 340, 680), ("PID2", "diag3", "diag4", 245, 490), ("PID2", "diag2", "diag1", 124, 248))

val claimRDD1 = sc.parallelize(claimsData1)
val claimRDDRow1 = claimRDD1.map(p => Row(p._1, p._2, p._3, p._4, p._5))
val claimRDD2DF1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(claimRDDRow1, Claim1)

val l = List("allowed", "allowed1")
val exprs = l.map((_ -> "sum")).toMap
claimRDD2DF1.groupBy("pid").agg(exprs) show false
val exprs = Map("allowed" -> "sum", "allowed1" -> "avg")

claimRDD2DF1.groupBy("pid").agg(exprs) show false
```

Answer (score 3):

Current answers are perfectly correct on how to create the aggregations, but none actually address the column alias/renaming that is also requested in the question.

Typically, this is how I handle this case:

```scala
val dimensionFields = List("col1")
val metrics = List("col2", "col3", "col4")
val columnOfInterests = dimensions ++ metrics

val df = spark.read.table("some_table") 
    .select(columnOfInterests.map(c => col(c)):_*)
    .groupBy(dimensions.map(d => col(d)): _*)
    .agg(metrics.map( m => m -> "sum").toMap)
    .toDF(columnOfInterests:_*)    // that's the interesting part
```

The last line essentially renames every columns of the aggregated dataframe to the original fields, essentially changing `sum(col2)` and `sum(col3)` to simply `col2` and `col3`.

Answer (score 2):

for pyspark, you can use below, which can combine different column names and aggregation functions, as wells renaming.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
dims = ["col1"]
mertrics = ["col2", "col3", "col4"]
aggFuncs = ["sum", "avg", "max"]

aggs = [expr(f"{a}({c}) as {c}_{a}") for c in metrics for a in aggFuncs]
# or you can also do below, they are equivalent
# aggs = [expr(f"{a}({c})").alias(f"{c}_{a}") for c in metrics for a in aggFuncs]

df.groupBy(*dims).agg(*aggs).show()
```