# Apply same function to all fields of spark dataframe row

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe in which I have about 1000s ( variable)  columns.

I want to make all values upper case.

Here is the approach I have thought of , can you suggest if this is best way.

- Take row
- Find schema and store in array and find how many fields are there.
- map through each row in data frame and upto limit of number of elements in array
- apply function to upper case each fields and return row

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you simply want to apply the same functions to all columns something like this should be enough:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, upper}

val df = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(("a", "B", "c"), ("D", "e", "F"))).toDF("x", "y", "z")
df.select(df.columns.map(c => upper(col(c)).alias(c)): _*).show

// +---+---+---+
// |  x|  y|  z|
// +---+---+---+
// |  A|  B|  C|
// |  D|  E|  F|
// +---+---+---+
```

or in Python

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, upper

df = sc.parallelize([("a", "B", "c"), ("D", "e", "F")]).toDF(("x", "y", "z"))
df.select(*(upper(col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns)).show()

##  +---+---+---+
##  |  x|  y|  z|
##  +---+---+---+
##  |  A|  B|  C|
##  |  D|  E|  F|
##  +---+---+---+
```

See also: [SparkSQL: apply aggregate functions to a list of column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33882894/1560062)

Comment: Thanks what is this doing in English .alias(c)): _*

Comment: `alias` sets a name for the column. `:_*` denotes varargs syntax in Scala. In other words it passes each element of the sequence as an argument for `select`.

Comment: getting this error ```File "<ipython-input-10-bd092d3f0048>", line 1
    pivoted.select(pivoted.columns.map(c => encodeUDF(col(c)).alias(c)): _*).show(2)
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do similar but had to write my own function to convert empty strings within a dataframe to null. This is what I did.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf} 
import spark.implicits._ 

def emptyToNull(_str: String): Option[String] = {
  _str match {
    case d if (_str == null || _str.trim.isEmpty) => None
    case _ => Some(_str)
  }
}
val emptyToNullUdf = udf(emptyToNull(_: String))

val df = Seq(("a", "B", "c"), ("D", "e ", ""), ("", "", null)).toDF("x", "y", "z")
df.select(df.columns.map(c => emptyToNullUdf(col(c)).alias(c)): _*).show

+----+----+----+
|   x|   y|   z|
+----+----+----+
|   a|   B|   c|
|   D|  e |null|
|null|null|null|
+----+----+----+
```

Here's a more refined function of emptyToNull using options instead of null.

```
def emptyToNull(_str: String): Option[String] = Option(_str) match {
  case ret @ Some(s) if (s.trim.nonEmpty) => ret
  case _ => None
}
```