# pyspark Column is not iterable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Having this dataframe I am getting Column is not iterable when I try to groupBy and getting max:

```
linesWithSparkDF
+---+-----+
| id|cycle|
+---+-----+
| 31|   26|
| 31|   28|
| 31|   29|
| 31|   97|
| 31|   98|
| 31|  100|
| 31|  101|
| 31|  111|
| 31|  112|
| 31|  113|
+---+-----+
only showing top 10 rows


ipython-input-41-373452512490> in runlgmodel2(model, data)
     65     linesWithSparkDF.show(10)
     66 
---> 67     linesWithSparkGDF = linesWithSparkDF.groupBy(col("id")).agg(max(col("cycle")))
     68     print "linesWithSparkGDF"
     69 

/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in __iter__(self)
    241 
    242     def __iter__(self):
--> 243         raise TypeError("Column is not iterable")
    244 
    245     # string methods

TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's because, you've overwritten the `max` definition provided by `apache-spark`, it was easy to spot because `max` was expecting an `iterable`.

To fix this, you can use [a different syntax](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=agg#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg), and it should work:

```py
linesWithSparkGDF = linesWithSparkDF.groupBy(col("id")).agg({"cycle": "max"})
```

Or, alternatively:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import max as sparkMax

linesWithSparkGDF = linesWithSparkDF.groupBy(col("id")).agg(sparkMax(col("cycle")))
```

Comment: Gee : ... i <3 scala!

Answer (score 32):

The **idiomatic** style for avoiding this problem -- which are unfortunate namespace collisions between some **Spark SQL function names** and **Python built-in function names** -- is to `import` the `Spark SQL functions module` like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
# USAGE: F.col(), F.max(), F.someFunc(), ...
```

Then, using the `OP's` example, you'd simply apply `F` like this:

```
linesWithSparkGDF = linesWithSparkDF.groupBy(F.col("id")) \
                               .agg(F.max(F.col("cycle")))
```

In practice, this is how the problem is avoided **idiomatically**. `=:)`

Comment: This approach is in-fact straight forward and works like a charm.

Comment: If I created a UDF  in Python? Is there some way to apply it on all columns? Think about... you created a function UDF to apply default format without special caracters and in uppercase.

Comment: Hi @FernandoDelago This question might help you generically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037889/apply-same-function-to-all-fields-of-spark-dataframe-row

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old but this might help someone.

First import the following :

`from pyspark.sql import functions as F`

Then

`linesWithSparkGDF = linesWithSparkDF.groupBy(col("id")).agg(F.max(col("cycle")))`

Comment: Should be `F.col` I guess?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue, although error looks mischievous but we can resolve the same to check if we missed the following import-

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

this will get the required functions to aggregate the data if datatypes of columns are right. I fixed the similar issue by adding the required import, so don't forget that to check...