# Pyspark 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm' error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to print total elements in each partitions in a DataFrame using spark 2.2

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def count_elements(splitIndex, iterator):
    n = sum(1 for _ in iterator)
    yield (splitIndex, n)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("tmp").getOrCreate()
num_parts = 3
df = spark.read.json("/tmp/tmp/gon_s.json").repartition(num_parts)
print("df has partitions."+ str(df.rdd.getNumPartitions()))
print("Elements across partitions is:" + str(df.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(lambda ind, x: count_elements(ind, x)).take(3)))
```

The Code above kept failing with following error

> ```python
>   n = sum(1 for _ in iterator)
>   File "/home/dev/wk/pyenv/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 40, in _
>     jc = getattr(sc._jvm.functions, name)(col._jc if isinstance(col, Column) else col)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
> ```

after removing the import below

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

Code works fine

```python
skewed_large_df has partitions.3
The distribution of elements across partitions is:[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```

What is it causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't do `import *` as it can mess up your namespace. Do `import pyspark.sql.functions as f` and call the functions from that module using `f.function_name()`. I'm pretty sure you meant to call the builitin `sum()` and not  `pyspark.sql.functions.sum()`. That's probably what's causing your issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that @pault. very helpful. I would except buildins.py sum method to have precedence over pyspark.sql.functions.sum() method!

Comment: I think @pault comment should be posted as answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyspark Column is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924873/pyspark-column-is-not-iterable).

Answer (score 16):

This is a great example of [why you shouldn't use `import *`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad).

The line

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

will bring in all the functions in the `pyspark.sql.functions` module into your namespace, include some that will shadow your builtins.

The specific issue is in the `count_elements` function on the line:

```python
n = sum(1 for _ in iterator)
#   ^^^ - this is now pyspark.sql.functions.sum
```

You intended to call `__builtin__.sum`, but the `import *` shadowed the builtin.

Instead, do one of the following:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
```

Or

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as sum_
```

Comment: This is a legit answer. I'm not closing this question. Can you remove your vote close please ? :)