# Can not create a max column, with list comprehension. sum column works

Tags: pyspark

I try to create a max column with this code. The sum column works

sum:

```
for col in list_names:
    for month in [3,6,9,12]:
        companies = companies.withColumn(col + 'sum_'+ str(month) + '_months', sum(companies[col + ult_pats2[month_ix - ix]] for ix in range(month)) )
```

max:

```
for col in list_names:
    for month in [3,6,9,12]:
        companies = companies.withColumn(col + 'max_'+ str(month) + '_months', max(companies[col + ult_pats2[month_ix - ix]] for ix in range(month)) )
```

the error message is:

> "ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for
>   'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean
>   expressions"

Comment: could you please share the expected input and output you want

Comment: [Did you do an `import *`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481363/pyspark-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-jvm-error/55711135#55711135)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked with this code, using sf.greatest:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

for col in list_names:  
    for month  in [3,6,9,12]:
            companies = companies.withColumn('max_'+ col + str(month) + '_months',
                                             sf.greatest( *[sf.col(col + ult_pats2[month_ix - ix]) for ix in range(month)] ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like overwriting the max function by some other package.
Try:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
```

And then use the reference `f.max(...)`

Comment: This option -f.max()- gets max value of one column, but it doesn't work with multiple columns.