# NameError: name 'split' is not defined with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, split, apache-spark-sql

I have been working on a big dataset with Spark. Last week when I ran the following lines of code it worked perfectly, now it is throwing an error: NameError: name 'split' is not defined. Can somebody explain why this is not working and what should I do? Name split is not defined... Should I define the method? Is it a dependency that I should import? The documentation doesn't say I ahve to import anything in order to use the split method. The code below.

```
test_df = spark_df.withColumn(
  "Keywords", 
   split(col("Keywords"), "\\|")
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.split()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split), but you first need to import this function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
```

---

It's better to explicitly import just the functions you need. [Do not do `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55711135/5858851).

Comment: Same error: "NameError: name 'split' is not defined"

Comment: Which version of pyspark do you use?

Comment: I am using '2.4.4'

Comment: Could you please try the import statement `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`?