# Pyspark - groupby([col list]).agg(count([col list))

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I achieve this ?

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)
grouped=df.groupby([col list]).agg(F.count([col list]))
```

I've read the similar questions on stackoverflow but could not find the exact answer.

Even if I try to put a single column

```
grouped=dfn.groupby('col name').agg(F.count('col name'))
```

I get -

py4j\java_collections.py", line 500, in convert
    for element in object:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Reference to question - [pyspark Column is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924873/pyspark-column-is-not-iterable)

**I don't know the column names beforehand and need to provide list as input to the group by agg functions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `.count()` method on `GroupedData` object.

Let's prepare some data (I assume you have `SparkSession` object available under `spark` variable)

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> pdf = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
>>> df.show(5)

+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------+
|sepal_length|sepal_width|petal_length|petal_width|species|
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------+
|         5.1|        3.5|         1.4|        0.2| setosa|
|         4.9|        3.0|         1.4|        0.2| setosa|
|         4.7|        3.2|         1.3|        0.2| setosa|
|         4.6|        3.1|         1.5|        0.2| setosa|
|         5.0|        3.6|         1.4|        0.2| setosa|
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Then simply use `groupBy(*cols)` method on desired column(s) in DataFrame.

```py
>>> grouped = df.groupBy(['petal_width', 'species']).count()
>>> grouped.show(5)

+-----------+----------+-----+
|petal_width|   species|count|
+-----------+----------+-----+
|        1.7| virginica|    1|
|        2.2| virginica|    3|
|        1.8| virginica|   11|
|        1.9| virginica|    5|
|        1.5|versicolor|   10|
+-----------+----------+-----+
only showing top 5 rows
```