# pyspark search dataframe and randomly select value to add to new dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

suppose I have two dataframes:`df`, `grp_df` which is df.groupby(["region"]).set_list()

df

```
 user        item        region
 james        I1         Canada
  amy         I5         Germany
 chris        I33        U.S.
```

grp_df

```
  region          Item_lst
  Canada         [I1, I2,... In]
  Germany        [ I3, I5, ... In]
  U.S.           [I33, I22, I11]
  ...             ...
```

For each user I want to select new item that is not bought before within same region and add it to new pyspark dataframe.

new_df

```
user      item        region
james       I2        Canada
amy         I3        Germany
chris       I22        U.S.
```

What is most efficient way to do this in pyspark?

My Approach:

```
df = df.join(grp_df, ["region"], "left")

def get_neg_sample(item, item_lst):
    return np.random.choice(item_lst.remove(item))

get_neg_sample_udf = udf(get_neg_sample, IntegerType())

df.withColumn("neg_item", get_neg_sample_udf("item", "item_lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is `array_contains` , you can make use of this with join to get your desired result

```
val newDf = df.join(gdf,df.col("country")===gdf.col("country") && !array_contains(gdf.col("item_list"),df.col("item")))
```

Comment: What does exclamation mark mean?

Comment: Sorry and gdf should have "item_lst" column

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the correct column name, exclamation is the not operator. Its basically saying array does not contain this value

Comment: hm.. not really understanding this. what is ===? trying to convert to pyspark however keep on failing..

Comment: in python it would be just `==` instead of `===`

Comment: but you are doing "country" == "item_lst" which does not make sense.

Comment: ya you are right, i made a copy paste error fixed it now

Comment: hm... python code = `df.join(gdf, [(df["region"] == gdf["region]), (~array_contains(gdf["item_lst"], df["item"])]` outputs `TypeError Column is not iterable`

Comment: maybe it should `gdf["Item_lst"]` instead of `gdf["item_lst"]`

Comment: nope, the name of column isn't it.

Comment: I guess this is your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924873/pyspark-column-is-not-iterable

array_contains is probably a python function can you rename it (as described in the answer) and try?

Comment: hm.. no that's not it either... hm...

Answer (score 0):

For spark 2.4+, you can use `shuffle` and `array_remove`.

```
new_df = df.join(grp_df, 'region').select('region', 'user', F.expr('shuffle(array_remove(Item_lst, item))[0]').alias('item'))
new_df.show(truncate=False)
```