# Pyspark - Aggregation on multiple columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I have data like below. Filename:babynames.csv.

```
year    name    percent     sex
1880    John    0.081541    boy
1880    William 0.080511    boy
1880    James   0.050057    boy
```

I need to sort the input based on year and sex and I want the output aggregated like below (this output is to be assigned to a new RDD).

```
year    sex   avg(percentage)   count(rows)
1880    boy   0.070703         3
```

I am not sure how to proceed after the following step in pyspark. Need your help on this

```
testrdd = sc.textFile("babynames.csv");
rows = testrdd.map(lambda y:y.split(',')).filter(lambda x:"year" not in x[0])
aggregatedoutput = ????
```

Answer (score 53):

1. Follow the instructions from [the README](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/README.md) to include [`spark-csv` package](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)
2. Load data

   ```
   df = (sqlContext.read
       .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
       .options(inferSchema="true", delimiter=";", header="true")
       .load("babynames.csv"))
   ```
3. Import required functions

   ```
   from pyspark.sql.functions import count, avg
   ```
4. Group by and aggregate (optionally use `Column.alias`:

   ```
   df.groupBy("year", "sex").agg(avg("percent"), count("*"))
   ```

**Alternatively**:

- cast `percent` to numeric
- reshape to a format ((`year`, `sex`), `percent`)
- `aggregateByKey` using  `pyspark.statcounter.StatCounter`

Comment: [SparkSQL: apply aggregate functions to a list of column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33882894/1560062) |

[Multiple Aggregate operations on the same column of a spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34954771/1560062).