# Apache SPark: groupby not working as expected

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

df

```
  Date          Col1   COl2
  2010-01-01     23     28
  2012-09-01     50     70
  2010-03-04     80     10
  2012-04-01     19      20
  2012-03-05     67      9

  df_new=df.withColumn('year',year(df['Date']))

  Date          Col1   COl2   year
  2010-01-01     23     28    2010
  2012-09-01     50     70    2012   and so on
```

Now, I am trying to find the maximum of Col1 and Col2 for each year. So I use groupby:

```
   df_new.groupby('year').max().show()
```

THe result I get is not what I expected. Result obtained

```
   year    max(year)
   2010    2010
   2012    2012   and so on
```

Expected result

```
    year    max(Col1)    max(Col2)
    2010     80            28
    2012     67             70
```

Comment: check what are the datatypes of Col1 and Col2..?

Comment: You can aggregate values of multiple columns using `.agg()`. Google can provide further assistance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251004/pyspark-aggregation-on-multiple-columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark - Aggregation on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251004/pyspark-aggregation-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: @mazaneicha just for my knowledge , i tried OPs code and it worked(returned aggregated values of all columns) , does this mean that the dtypes are not numeric? ( is this the reason why it didnt work for OP or do you foresee any other issues..) )aggregate with max would still work on a string but might be inconsistent.., thanks :)

Comment: @anky right, _max(*cols)[source]
Computes the max value for each **numeric** columns for each group._  And if OP tried `df_new.groupby('year').max('Col1').show()` they would get "Col1 is not a numeric column" or smth like that.

Comment: @mazaneicha Thanks, so then there might be another question saying max not working correctly :)

Comment: looks like thats where this is headed :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('year',F.year(df['date'])).groupBy("year").agg(F.max("col1").alias("max_col1"),F.max("col2").alias("max_col2")).show()
```

Comment: Error `F` is not defined

Comment: added import , check now.

Answer (score 1):

you should perform multiple `max` , `agg` on the `Col1` and `Col2`

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df_new.groupBy(F.year("Date")).agg(F.max("Col1"),F.max("Col2"))
      .show()
```

Comment: happy to help @ShailajaGuptaKapoor

Comment: THis does not answer my question as i wanted to groupby year. YOur answer groups by date, but sill upvoted.....thanks for help

Comment: updated the ans to extract year from date column @ShailajaGuptaKapoor

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a huge dataset it is better to use a Window function in such cases as below , This performs way better than groupBy

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
df = spark.table("test_poc")
df = df.withColumn("Year", F.year(F.col('date')))
_w = W.partitionBy(F.col('year'))
df = df.withColumn('max_col', F.max('id').over(_w)).withColumn('min_col', F.min('id').over(_w))
df.show()
```

---------OUTPUT------------

```
+---+-------------------+----+-------+-------+
| id|               date|Year|max_col|min_col|
+---+-------------------+----+-------+-------+
|  5|2019-12-31 23:26:59|2019|      5|      2|
|  2|2019-12-31 23:26:59|2019|      5|      2|
|  1|1969-12-31 23:26:59|1969|      3|      1|
|  2|1969-12-31 23:26:30|1969|      3|      1|
|  3|1969-12-31 23:26:26|1969|      3|      1|
|  4|2020-12-31 23:26:59|2020|      4|      1|
|  1|2020-12-31 23:26:59|2020|      4|      1|
+---+-------------------+----+-------+-------+
```