# Spark DataFrame: Multiple Aggregation function on Multiple column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have list of aggregation function, alias and other as JSON configuration, like

```
{
    "aggregation": [{
        "alias_column_name1": {
            "sum": "<columnName1>"
        }
    }, {
        "alias_column_name2": {
            "sum": "<columnName1>"
        }
    }]
}
```

Currently I have executing same by following code:

```
val col1:Column = sum(<dataframeName>(<columnName1>)).alias(<alias_column_name1>)
val col2:Column = sum(<dataframeName>(<columnName2>)).alias(<alias_column_name2>)
dataframe.groupby(..).agg(col1, col2)
```

But I have many aggregation configuration and I want to pass List of such in aggregation method, like

```
val colList = List[Column](col1, col2)
dataframe.groupby(..).agg(colList)
```

How can I achieve same? Thanks

Versions:

```
Scala : 2.11
Spark : 2.2.2
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.2.2"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Separate list of columns and functions**

Let's say you have a list of functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val funs: Seq[Column => Column] = Seq(sum _, min _, max _)
```

and a list of columns

```
val cols: Seq[Column] = Seq($"y", $"z")
```

and a dataset

```
val df = Seq((1, 2, 3), (1, 4, 5) ).toDF("x", "y", "z")
```

you can combine both

```
val exprs = for { c <- cols; f <- funs} yield f(c)
```

and then

```
df.groupBy($"x").agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*)
```

The same thing could be done in PySpark:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

funs = [F.sum, F.min, F.max]
cols = ["y", "z"]

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 3), (1, 4, 5)], ("x", "y", "z"))

df.groupBy("x").agg(*[f(c) for c in cols for f in funs])
```

**Predefined list of operations for each column**

If you want start with predefined set of aliases, columns and functions, as the one shown in your question, it might be easier to just restructure it to

```
trait AggregationOp {
  def expr: Column
}

case class FuncAggregationOp(c: Column, func: Column => Column, alias: String
    ) extends AggregationOp {
  def expr = func(c).alias(alias)
}

val ops: Seq[AggregationOp] = Seq(
   FuncAggregationOp($"y", sum _, "alias_column_name1"),
   FuncAggregationOp($"z", sum _, "alias_column_name2")
)
val exprs = ops.map(_.expr)

df.groupBy($"x").agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*)
```

You can easily adjust this to handle other cases:

```
case class StringAggregationOp(c: String, func: String, alias: String
    ) extends AggregationOp {
  def expr = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr(s"${func}(`${c}`)").alias(alias)
}

val ops: Seq[AggregationOp] = Seq(
   StringAggregationOp("y", "sum", "alias_column_name1"),
   StringAggregationOp("z", "sum", "alias_column_name2")
)
```

Python equivalent could be something like this:

```py
from collections import namedtuple
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

class AggregationOp(namedtuple("Op", ["c", "func", "alias"])):
    def expr(self):
        if callable(self.func):
            return self.func(self.c).alias(self.alias)
        else:
            return F.expr("{func}(`{c}`)".format
                (func = self.func, c = self.c)).alias(self.alias)

ops = [
    AggregationOp("y", "sum", "alias_column_name1"),
    AggregationOp("z", "sum", "alias_column_name2")
]

 df.groupBy("x").agg(*[op.expr() for op in ops])
```

**Related question**:

- [Multiple Aggregate operations on the same column of a spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34954771/10465355)
- [SparkSQL: apply aggregate functions to a list of column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33882894/10465355)