# Spark Scala Data Frame to have multiple aggregation of single Group By

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark Scala Data Frame to have multiple aggregation of single group by.
eg

```
val groupped = df.groupBy("firstName", "lastName").sum("Amount").toDF()
```

But What if I need Count, Sum, Max etc

```
/* Below Does Not Work  , but this is what the intention is  
val groupped = df.groupBy("firstName", "lastName").sum("Amount").count().toDF()
*/
```

output
 `groupped.show()`

```
--------------------------------------------------
| firstName | lastName| Amount|count | Max | Min  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: // Compute the max age and average salary, grouped by department and gender.
ds.groupBy($"department", $"gender").agg(Map(
  "salary" -> "avg",
  "age" -> "max"
))

see groupyBy in the documentation for examples
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

Comment: @user10958683 True.. Its a Duplicate , But Zaks answer is more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case class soExample(firstName: String, lastName: String, Amount: Int)
val df =  Seq(soExample("me", "zack", 100)).toDF

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val groupped = df.groupBy("firstName", "lastName").agg(
     sum("Amount"),
     mean("Amount"), 
     stddev("Amount"),
     count(lit(1)).alias("numOfRecords")
   ).toDF()

display(groupped)
```