# PySpark: Groupby on multiple columns with multiple functions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running PySpark with Spark 2.0 to aggregate data. 
Below is the raw Dataframe (df) as received in Spark.

```
DeviceID    TimeStamp           IL1    IL2    IL3    VL1    VL2    VL3
1001        2019-07-14 00:45    2.1    3.1   2.25    235    258    122
1002        2019-07-14 01:15    3.2    2.4   4.25    240    250    192
1003        2019-07-14 01:30    3.2    2.0   3.85    245    215    192
1003        2019-07-14 01:30    3.9    2.8   4.25    240    250    192
```

Now I want to apply `groupby` logic by `DeviceID`. There are several posts there in StackOverflow. Particularly, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954771/multiple-aggregate-operations-on-the-same-column-of-a-spark-dataframe) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882894/spark-sql-apply-aggregate-functions-to-a-list-of-columns) links are of point of interest. With the help of those posts I created the following script

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
groupby = ["DeviceID"]
agg_cv = ["IL1","IL2","IL3","VL1","VL2","VL3"]
func = [min,max]
expr_cv = [F.f(F.col(c)) for f in func for c in agg_cv]
df_final = df_cv_filt.groupby(*groupby).agg(*expr_cv)
```

The above code is showing error as

```
Columns are not iterable
```

Not able to understand why such error is coming. When I am using the following code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import min, max, col
expr_cv = [f(col(c)) for f in func for c in agg_cv]
```

Then the above code is running fine.

My question is: how can I fix the above mentioned error.

Comment: Using `func = [F.min,F.max]` instead of `func = [min,max]`.

Comment: Thanks @giser_yugang. Let me check and revert.

Comment: Exactly. min, max by default are for python's default min and max. to use PySpark's  min and max we can have F.min and F.max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
func = [F.min,F.max]
agg_cv = ["IL1","IL2","IL3","VL1","VL2","VL3"]
expr_cv = [f(F.col(c)) for f in func for c in agg_cv]
df_final = df1.groupby(*groupby).agg(*expr_cv)
```

This should work.

````
+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|DeviceID|min( IL1)|min(IL2)|min(IL3)|min(VL1)|min(VL2)|min(VL3)|max( IL1)|max(IL2)|max(IL3)|max(VL1)|max(VL2)|max(VL3)|
+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    1003|      3.2|     2.0|    3.85|     240|     215|     192|      3.9|     2.8|    4.25|     245|     250|     192|
|    1002|      3.2|     2.4|    4.25|     240|     250|     192|      3.2|     2.4|    4.25|     240|     250|     192|
|    1001|      2.1|     3.1|    2.25|     235|     258|     122|      2.1|     3.1|    2.25|     235|     258|     122|
+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+```
````