# Extend Groupby to include multiply aggregation

Tags: sql, scala, group-by

I implemented a groupby function which groups columns based on a particular aggregation successfully.  The issue is I am using a argument for chosen columns and aggregation as  Map[String,String] which means multiple aggregations cannot be performed on one column. for example sum, mean and max all on one column.
below is what works soo far:

groupByFunction(input, Map("someSignal" -> "mean"))

```
def groupByFunction(dataframeDummy: DataFrame,
                  columnsWithOperation: Map[String,String],
                  someSession: String = "sessionId",
                  someSignal: String = "signalName"): DataFrame = {

    dataframeDummy
      .groupBy(
         col(someSession),
          col(someSignal)
      ).agg(columnsWithOperation)

  }
```

Upon looking into it a bit more, the agg function can take a list of columns like below

```
 userData
      .groupBy(
        window(
          (col(timeStampColumnName) / lit(millisSecondsPerSecond)).cast(TimestampType),
          timeWindowInS.toString.concat(" seconds")
        ),
        col(sessionColumnName),
        col(signalColumnName)
      ).agg(
      mean("physicalSignalValue"),
      sum("physicalSignalValue")).show()
```

So I decided to try to manipulate the input to look like that, below is how I did it:

```
val signalIdColumn = columnsWithOperation.toSeq.flatMap { case (key, list) => list.map(key -> _) }

 val result = signalIdColumn.map(tuple =>
      if (tuple._2 == "mean")
        mean(tuple._1)
      else if (tuple._2 == "sum")
        sum(tuple._1)
      else if (tuple._2 == "max")
        max(tuple._1))
```

Now I have a list of columns, which is still a problem for agg funciton.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using a sequence of tuples like this Seq[(String, String)] instead of Map[String,String]

```
def groupByFunction(dataframeDummy: DataFrame,
                  columnsWithOperation: Seq[(String, String)],
                  someSession: String = "sessionId",
                  someSignal: String = "signalName"): DataFrame = {

    dataframeDummy
      .groupBy(
         col(someSession),
          col(someSignal)
      ).agg(columnsWithOperation)
```

and then with the information

from below post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34955432/2091294

```
userData
      .groupBy(
        col(someSession),
        col(someSignal)
      ).agg(columnsWithOperation.head, columnsWithOperation.tail: _*)
```