# Avarage per group in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, average

I have PySpark dataframe below:

```
cust |  amount |  
----------------
A    |  5      |  
A    |  1      |
A    |  3      |     
B    |  4      |     
B    |  4      |     
B    |  2      |     
C    |  2      |     
C    |  1      |     
C    |  7      |     
C    |  5      |
```

I need to group by column `'cust'` and calculates the average per group.

Expected result:

```
cust |  avg_amount
-------------------
A    |  3
B    |  3.333
C    |  7.5
```

I've been using the code as below but giving me the error.

`data.withColumn("avg_amount", F.avg("amount"))`

Any idea how I can make this average?

Comment: how is the amount column determined? it seems to be randomly picked for each cust.

Comment: What is the rule for the column `amount` in the expected output? Why it's `3` for group `A` for example?

Comment: there's no rule in column ```amount```. It is transactional row. Depends on how many transaction the customer is doing.

Comment: So shouldn't it be 2 for B and 4 for C? They have respectively 2 and 4 transactions in the input table.

Comment: yes, let me edit my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Aggregate operations on the same column of a spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954771/multiple-aggregate-operations-on-the-same-column-of-a-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupBy` to count the number of transactions and the average of `amount` by customer:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = data.groupBy("cust")\
           .agg(
               F.count("*").alias("amount"),
               F.avg("amount").alias("avg_amount")
           )
```