# Spark reduce and aggregate on same data-set

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions

I have a text file which I read and then split using the `split` operation. This results in an RDD with `Array(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I)`.

I would like to find `max(F) - min(G)` for every key `E` (reduce by key `E`). Then  I want to combine the resulting values by key `C` and concatenate this sum result for every row with the same key.

For example:

```
+--+--+--+--+
| C| E| F| G|
+--+--+--+--+
|en| 1| 3| 1|
|en| 1| 4| 0|
|nl| 2| 1| 1|
|nl| 2| 5| 2|
|nl| 3| 9| 3|
|nl| 3| 6| 4|
|en| 4| 9| 1|
|en| 4| 2| 1|
+-----------+
```

Should result in

```
+--+--+-------------+---+
| C| E|max(F)-min(G)|sum|
+--+--+-------------+---+
|en| 1| 4           |12 |
|nl| 2| 4           |10 |
|nl| 3| 6           |10 |
|en| 4| 8           |12 |
+--+--+-------------+---+
```

What would be the best way to tackle this? Currently I am trying to perform the `max(F)-min(G)` by running

```
val maxCounts = logEntries.map(line => (line(4), line(5).toLong)).reduceByKey((x, y) => math.max(x, y))
val minCounts = logEntries.map(line => (line(4), line(6).toLong)).reduceByKey((x, y) => math.min(x, y))

val maxMinCounts = maxCounts.join(minCounts).map{ case(id, maxmin) => (id, (maxmin._1 - maxmin._2)) }
```

And then `join` the resulting RDDs. However, this becomes tricky when I also want to sum these values and append them to my existing data set.

I would love to hear any suggestions!

Comment: It is easy when you work with Spark SQL DataFrame, you can convert your RDD to DataFrame and do all the aggregate operations.. try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882894/sparksql-apply-aggregate-functions-to-a-list-of-column

Comment: Why not combine `math.max` and `math.min` into the same RDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of logic is easily implemented in the dataframe API (also). But you need to explicitly form your columns from the array:

```
val window = Window.partitionBy('C)

val df = rdd
  .map { case Array(_, _, c, _, e, f, g, _, _) => (c,e,f,g) }
  .toDF("C","E","F","G")
  .groupBy('C,'E)
  .agg((max('F) - min('G)).as("diff"))
  .withColumn("sum",sum('diff).over(window))
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I changed `sum(diff)` to `sum('diff)` and `Window.partitionBy('v)` to `Window.partitionBy('C)` because it would result in an error otherwise. However, when I try running this code I get the following error: `scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@f908897 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)`.

Using `Window.partitionBy('v)` resulted in `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '\`v\`' given input columns: [C, E, diff];`.

Comment: I solved this problem by using the Spark CSV reader instead of reading the input file directly. The problem probably had to do with special characters in the input.

Answer (score 1):

assuming, like your sample data, that unique E's never span multiple C's...  you could do something like this.

```
import math.{max,min}

case class FG(f: Int, g: Int) {
  def combine(that: FG) =
    FG(max(f, that.f), min(g, that.g))
  def result = f - g 
}

val result = {
  rdd
  .map{ case Array(_, _, c, _, e, f, g, _, _) => 
    ((c, e), FG(f, g)) }
  .reduceByKey(_ combine _)
  .map{ case ((c, _), fg) =>
    (c, fg.result) }
  .reduceByKey(_+_)  
}
```