# How to iterate grouped data in spark?

Tags: java, sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset like this:

```
uid    group_a    group_b
1      3          unkown
1      unkown     4
2      unkown     3
2      2          unkown
```

I want to get the result:

```
uid    group_a    group_b
1      3          4
2      2          3
```

I try to group the data by "uid" and iterate each group and select the not-unkown value as the final value, but don't know how to do it.

Comment: by `unknown` you mean `null` ?

Comment: some data is String type, the value is "unkown", which should be discard

Comment: so all your cols ars string?

Comment: please drop some code which you have difficulties with. Its should be the same way like you operate with usual scala collection. you should get pairRDD I would assume: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you define a `User Defined Aggregation Function` (`UDAF`)

Using `inbuilt functions` are great ways but they are difficult to be customized. If you own a `UDAF` then it is customizable and you can edit it according to your needs.

Concerning your problem, following can be your solution. You can edit it according to your needs.

First task is to define a `UDAF`

```
class PingJiang extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

  def inputSchema = new StructType().add("group_a", StringType).add("group_b", StringType)
  def bufferSchema = new StructType().add("buff0", StringType).add("buff1", StringType)
  def dataType = StringType
  def deterministic = true

  def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {
    buffer.update(0, "")
    buffer.update(1, "")
  }

  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {
    if (!input.isNullAt(0)) {
      val buff = buffer.getString(0)
      val groupa = input.getString(0)
      val groupb = input.getString(1)

      if(!groupa.equalsIgnoreCase("unknown")){
        buffer.update(0, groupa)
      }
      if(!groupb.equalsIgnoreCase("unknown")){
        buffer.update(1, groupb)
      }
    }
  }

  def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
    val buff1 = buffer1.getString(0)+buffer2.getString(0)
    val buff2 = buffer1.getString(1)+buffer2.getString(1)
    buffer1.update(0, buff1+","+buff2)
  }

  def evaluate(buffer: Row) : String = {
    buffer.getString(0)
  }
}
```

Then you call it from your `main` class and do some manipulations to get the result you need as

```
val data = Seq(
  (1, "3", "unknown"),
  (1, "unknown", "4"),
  (2, "unknown", "3"),
  (2, "2", "unknown"))
  .toDF("uid", "group_a", "group_b")

val udaf = new PingJiang()

val result = data.groupBy("uid").agg(udaf($"group_a", $"group_b").as("ping"))
  .withColumn("group_a", split($"ping", ",")(0))
  .withColumn("group_b", split($"ping", ",")(1))
  .drop("ping")
result.show(false)
```

Visit [databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udaf-scala.html) and [augmentiq](https://blog.augmentiq.in/2016/08/05/spark-multiple-inputoutput-user-defined-aggregate-function-udaf-using-java/) for better understanding of `UDAF`

**Note : The above solution gets you the latest value for each group if present (You can always edit according to your needs)**

Answer (score 0):

After you format the dataset to a PairRDD you can use the reduceByKey operation to find the single known value. The following example assumes that there is only one known value per uid or otherwise returns the first known value

```
val input = List(
    ("1", "3", "unknown"),
    ("1", "unknown", "4"),
    ("2", "unknown", "3"),
    ("2", "2", "unknown")
)

val pairRdd = sc.parallelize(input).map(l => (l._1, (l._2, l._3)))

val result = pairRdd.reduceByKey { (a, b) => 
    val groupA = if (a._1 != "unknown") a._1 else b._1
    val groupB = if (a._2 != "unknown") a._2 else b._2
    (groupA, groupB)
}
```

The result will be a pairRdd that looks like this

```
(uid, (group_a, group_b))
(1,(3,4))                                                                       
(2,(2,3))
```

You can return to the plain line format with a simple map operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all `"unknown"` values by `null`, and then use the function `first()` inside a map (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33907419/4964651)), to get the first non-null values in each column per group:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col,first,when}
// We are only gonna apply our function to the last 2 columns
val cols = df.columns.drop(1)
// Create expression
val exprs = cols.map(first(_,true))
// Putting it all together
df.select(df.columns
          .map(c => when(col(c) === "unknown", null)
          .otherwise(col(c)).as(c)): _*)
  .groupBy("uid")
  .agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*).show()
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|uid|first(group_1, true)|first(group_b, true)|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1|                   3|                   4|
|  2|                   2|                   3|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

**Data:**

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array(("1","3","unknown"),("1","unknown","4"),
                              ("2","unknown","3"),("2","2","unknown"))).toDF("uid","group_1","group_b")
```