# How to iterate grouped rows to produce multiple rows in spark structured streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, etl

I have the input data set like:

```
id     operation          value
1      null                1
1      discard             0
2      null                1
2      null                2
2      max                 0
3      null                1
3      null                1
3      list                0
```

I want to group the input and produce rows according to "operation" column.

for group 1, operation="discard", then the output is null,

for group 2, operation="max", the output is:

```
2      null                2
```

for group 3, operation="list", the output is:

```
3      null                1
3      null                1
```

So finally the output is like:

```
  id     operation          value
   2      null                2
   3      null                1
   3      null                1
```

Is there a solution for this?

I know there is a similar question [how-to-iterate-grouped-data-in-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131219/how-to-iterate-grouped-data-in-spark)
But the differences compared to that are:

- 1. I want to produce more than one row for each grouped data. Possible
     and how?
  2. I want my logic to be easily extended for more operation to be added in  future. So User-defined aggregate functions (aka UDAF) is
     the only possible solution?

***Update 1:***

Thank stack0114106, then more details according to his answer, e.g. for id=1, operation="max", I want to iterate all the item with id=2, and find the max value, rather than assign a hard-coded value, that's why I want to iterate the rows in each group. Below is a updated example:

The input:

```
scala> val df = Seq((0,null,1),(0,"discard",0),(1,null,1),(1,null,2),(1,"max",0),(2,null,1),(2,null,3),(2,"max",0),(3,null,1),(3,null,1),(3,"list",0)).toDF("id"
,"operation","value")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, operation: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show(false)
+---+---------+-----+
|id |operation|value|
+---+---------+-----+
|0  |null     |1    |
|0  |discard  |0    |
|1  |null     |1    |
|1  |null     |2    |
|1  |max      |0    |
|2  |null     |1    |
|2  |null     |3    |
|2  |max      |0    |
|3  |null     |1    |
|3  |null     |1    |
|3  |list     |0    |
+---+---------+-----+
```

The expected output:

```
+---+---------+-----+
|id |operation|value|
+---+---------+-----+
|1  |null     |2    |
|2  |null     |3    |
|3  |null     |1    |
|3  |null     |1    |
+---+---------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flatMap operation on the dataframe and generate required rows based on the conditions that you mentioned. Check this out

```
scala> val df = Seq((1,null,1),(1,"discard",0),(2,null,1),(2,null,2),(2,"max",0),(3,null,1),(3,null,1),(3,"list",0)).toDF("id","operation","value")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, operation: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show(false)
+---+---------+-----+
|id |operation|value|
+---+---------+-----+
|1  |null     |1    |
|1  |discard  |0    |
|2  |null     |1    |
|2  |null     |2    |
|2  |max      |0    |
|3  |null     |1    |
|3  |null     |1    |
|3  |list     |0    |
+---+---------+-----+


scala> df.filter("operation is not null").flatMap( r=> { val x=r.getString(1); val s = x match { case "discard" => (0,0) case "max" => (1,2) case "list" => (2,1) } ; (0
 until s._1).map( i => (r.getInt(0),null,s._2) ) }).show(false)
+---+----+---+
|_1 |_2  |_3 |
+---+----+---+
|2  |null|2  |
|3  |null|1  |
|3  |null|1  |
+---+----+---+
```

Spark assigns _1,_2 etc.. so you can map them to actual names by assigning them as below

```
scala> val df2 = df.filter("operation is not null").flatMap( r=> { val x=r.getString(1); val s = x match { case "discard" => (0,0) case "max" => (1,2) case "list" => (2,1) } ; (0 until s._1).map( i => (r.getInt(0),null,s._2) ) }).toDF("id","operation","value")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, operation: null ... 1 more field]

scala> df2.show(false)
+---+---------+-----+
|id |operation|value|
+---+---------+-----+
|2  |null     |2    |
|3  |null     |1    |
|3  |null     |1    |
+---+---------+-----+


scala>
```

**EDIT1:**

Since you need the max(value) for each id, you can use window functions and get the max value in a new column, then use the same technique and get the results. Check this out

```
scala> val df =   Seq((0,null,1),(0,"discard",0),(1,null,1),(1,null,2),(1,"max",0),(2,null,1),(2,null,3),(2,"max",0),(3,null,1),(3,null,1),(3,"list",0)).toDF("id","operation","value")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, operation: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("michael")

scala> val df2 = spark.sql(""" select *, max(value) over(partition by id) mx from michael """)
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, operation: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> df2.show(false)
+---+---------+-----+---+
|id |operation|value|mx |
+---+---------+-----+---+
|1  |null     |1    |2  |
|1  |null     |2    |2  |
|1  |max      |0    |2  |
|3  |null     |1    |1  |
|3  |null     |1    |1  |
|3  |list     |0    |1  |
|2  |null     |1    |3  |
|2  |null     |3    |3  |
|2  |max      |0    |3  |
|0  |null     |1    |1  |
|0  |discard  |0    |1  |
+---+---------+-----+---+


scala> val df3 = df2.filter("operation is not null").flatMap( r=> { val x=r.getString(1); val s = x match { case "discard" => 0 case "max" => 1 case "list" => 2 } ; (0 until s).map( i => (r.getInt(0),null,r.getInt(3) )) }).toDF("id","operation","value")
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, operation: null ... 1 more field]


scala> df3.show(false)
+---+---------+-----+
|id |operation|value|
+---+---------+-----+
|1  |null     |2    |
|3  |null     |1    |
|3  |null     |1    |
|2  |null     |3    |
+---+---------+-----+


scala>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But still some issues: e.g. for operation="max", I want to iterate all the item with id=2, and find the max value, rather than assign a hard-coded value "2", that's why I want to iterate the rows in each group.  Please see "Update 1" in my question.

Comment: Please check my ````EDIT1````

Comment: Thanks stack0114106! This works for me although I need more time to digest.

Comment: glad that it works for you.. using window functions you can get the results of aggregate values in the "columns" as opposed to how you get at the bottom in traditional group-by query.. the window functions has it's own syntax..so it might take sometime for you to become comfortable..

Answer (score 1):

group everything collecting the values, then write logic for each operation :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val grouped=df.groupBy($"id").agg(max($"operation").as("op"),collect_list($"value").as("vals"))
val maxs=grouped.filter($"op"==="max").withColumn("val",explode($"vals")).groupBy($"id").agg(max("val").as("value"))
val lists=grouped.filter($"op"==="list").withColumn("value",explode($"vals")).filter($"value"!==0).select($"id",$"value")
//we don't collect the "discard"
//and we can add additional subsets for new "operations"
val result=maxs.union(lists)
//if you need the null in "operation" column add it with withColumn
```