# Spark dataframe : how to use as after a groupBy + sum

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

My question is quite simple, but I can't seem to find a proper solution. I can hack it with horrible code, I would like to find something elegant.

Here is my line of code :

```
    val summedDF = dataFrame.groupBy(colsNamesGroupBy.head, colsNamesGroupBy.tail : _*).sum(colsNamesSum:_*)
```

It does a groupBy on an array of column Names, and then sum a few columns.

Everything works fine, but I get columns with the folowing name : sum(xxxx). 
I would like to rename these on the go, maybe with a map operation, so I only keep the "xxxx" name.

Anyone has any idea ?

EDIT :

I'm trying something like that, but I get "cannot resolve symbol agg with this signature" :

```
    val summedDF = dataFrame.groupBy(colsNamesGroupBy.head, colsNamesGroupBy.tail : _*).agg(colsNamesSum.map(c => sum(c).as(c)))
```

Comment: Did you take a look into this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882894/sparksql-apply-aggregate-functions-to-a-list-of-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like that:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{sum, col}

val aggregateExpr = colsNamesSum.map(c => sum(col(c)).as(c))

val summedDF = dataFrame.groupBy(colsNamesGroupBy.head, colsNamesGroupBy.tail : _*).agg(aggregateExpr.head, aggregateExpr.tail: _*)
```

Comment: I would really like to make this work as this is the kind of solution I'm looking for

Comment: I get typeMismatch exception

Comment: Sorry, I migrated to Spark 2.1.1 recently, so there were some changes in .agg() method, I didn't know about. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This worked in my case (Spark 2.1.1). Please, try it out.

Comment: Now I have to find how to only keep the second colomn with the same name :p

Answer (score 0):

You need to import

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

So you can use `.agg`