# Aggregate multiple columns using methods that can't be called directly from GroupedData class (like "last()") and rename them to original names

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Assuming we have the following DF

```
scala> df.show
+---+----+----+----+-------------------+---+
| id|name| cnt| amt|                 dt|scn|
+---+----+----+----+-------------------+---+
|  1|null|   1|1.12|2000-01-02 00:11:11|112|
|  1| aaa|   1|1.11|2000-01-01 00:00:00|111|
|  2| bbb|null|2.22|2000-01-03 12:12:12|201|
|  2|null|   2|1.13|               null|200|
|  2|null|null|2.33|               null|202|
|  3| ccc|   3|3.34|               null|302|
|  3|null|null|3.33|               null|301|
|  3|null|null| 0.0|2000-12-31 23:59:59|300|
+---+----+----+----+-------------------+---+
```

I want to get the following DF - sorted by `scn`, groupped by `id` and take the last not-null value for every column (except `id` and `scn`).

It can be done like this:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

df.orderBy("scn")
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(last("name", true) as "name",
       last("cnt", true) as "cnt",
       last("amt", true) as "amt",
       last("dt", true) as "dt")
  .show

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+---+----+---+----+-------------------+
| id|name|cnt| amt|                 dt|
+---+----+---+----+-------------------+
|  1| aaa|  1|1.12|2000-01-02 00:11:11|
|  3| ccc|  3|3.34|2000-12-31 23:59:59|
|  2| bbb|  2|2.33|2000-01-03 12:12:12|
+---+----+---+----+-------------------+
```

In real life I want to process different DFs with a large amount of columns.

**My question is** - how can i specify all columns (except `id` and `scn`) in the `.agg(last(col_name, true))` **programmatically**?

Code for generating a source DF:

```
case class C(id: Integer, name: String, cnt: Integer, amt: Double, dt: String, scn: Integer)

val cc = Seq(
  C(1, null, 1, 1.12, "2000-01-02 00:11:11", 112),
  C(1, "aaa", 1, 1.11, "2000-01-01 00:00:00", 111),
  C(2, "bbb", null, 2.22, "2000-01-03 12:12:12", 201),
  C(2, null, 2, 1.13, null,200),
  C(2, null, null, 2.33, null, 202),
  C(3, "ccc", 3, 3.34, null, 302),
  C(3, null, null, 3.33, "20001-01-01 00:33:33", 301),
  C(3, null, null, 0.00, "2000-12-31 23:59:59", 300)
)

val t = sc.parallelize(cc, 4).toDF()
val df = t.withColumn("dt", $"dt".cast("timestamp"))
val cols = df.columns.filterNot(_.equals("id"))
```

Comment: @user8371915, thank you for the link! I've already read it some months before and even upvoted it that time, but i couldn't find it this time. I've posted an answer which additionally renames columns after aggregating - with a hope that it might help someone in future...

Comment: Can you help with bad information on this SO answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48346011/6361531

Answer (score 1):

Solution similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33907419/5741205), plus renaming columns in the resulting DF to the original ones:

```
val exprs = df.columns.filterNot(_.equals("id")).map(last(_, true))
val r = df.orderBy("scn").groupBy("id").agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*).toDF(df.columns:_*)
```

Result:

```
scala> r.show
+---+----+---+----+-------------------+---+
| id|name|cnt| amt|                 dt|scn|
+---+----+---+----+-------------------+---+
|  1| aaa|  1|1.12|2000-01-02 00:11:11|112|
|  3| ccc|  3|3.34|2000-12-31 23:59:59|302|
|  2| bbb|  2|2.33|2000-01-03 12:12:12|202|
+---+----+---+----+-------------------+---+
```

or:

```
val exprs = df.columns.filterNot(_.equals("id")).map(c=>last(c, true).as(c.toString))
val r = df.orderBy("scn").groupBy("id").agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*)
```