# Remove Blank Values from Spark DataFrame and merge into single row

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is my input DataFrame:

```
number|word|ID |Name|
+------+----+---+----+
|1     |    |   |    |
|      |abc |   |    |
|      |    |103|    |
|      |    |   |Dev |
+------+----+---+----
```

I want to remove the blank values and want to merge all the rows into single row like this:

```
number|word|ID |Name|
+------+----+---+----+
|1     | abc|103| Dev
```

First of all is it possible in spark? If yes then what is the best way to achieve. I am using Scala and Spark 2.1. Also, I can have n no.of columns.

Comment: is that the only data? if you have more data in the input then please update the question with some more sample data in the input and desired expected output?

Comment: As of now I have this as a sample data. My main motive is to remove the blank values from every row.

Comment: I think a different type of the dataset would explain it better. What if there's only one blank field in the entire row or all blank fields. Your example isn't complete. try to provide a [mcve]

Comment: for every row there will be only on column populated and rest are blank.

Comment: @user8371915 what if I have n no.of columns ??

Comment: Then [SparkSQL: apply aggregate functions to a list of column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33882894/8371915)

Comment: @user8371915 the solution works when values are null not with the blank values. Is there a way where I can convert the blank values to null ??

Comment: Try `first(when(trim(col(c)) =!= "", col(c)), true)`