# Merge columns into single map with UDF from Array of Column Names

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

So I have a dataframe of values that need to be summed together, then put into a `Map[String,Long]` format to save into Cassandra.

The below code works, however I was wondering if a map could be created based on an abstract list of columns. (Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala) for their functions only makes me more confused).

```
var cols = Array("key", "v1", "v2")
var df = Seq(("a",1,0),("b",1,0),("a",1,1),("b",0,0)).toDF(cols: _*)
val df1 = df.groupBy(col(cols(0))).
  agg(map(lit(cols(1)), sum(col(cols(1))), lit(cols(2)), sum(col(cols(2)))) as "map")
```

This is my desired format for the dataframe & current given outcome with above code:

```
scala> df1.show(false)
+---+---------------------+
|key|map                  |
+---+---------------------+
|b  |Map(v1 -> 1, v2 -> 0)|
|a  |Map(v1 -> 2, v2 -> 1)|
+---+---------------------+
```

I would like to see a function that can returns the same as above but be able to place columns programmatically based on name. E.g.:

```
var columnNames = Array("v1", "v2")
df.groupBy(col(cols(0))).agg(create_sum_map(columnNames) as "map")
```

Is this even remotely possible in Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a slow `UDF`, you can achieve this with pure in-built Spark functions and varargs, see e.g. [Spark SQL: apply aggregate functions to a list of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882894/spark-sql-apply-aggregate-functions-to-a-list-of-columns). This solution requires building a list of columns on which the aggregation can be applied on. Here, it's a bit more complicated since you want a `map` in the final output, this requires an extra step.

First create the expressions (columns) to be use in the aggregation:

```
val exprs = cols.tail.flatMap(c => Seq(lit(c), sum(col(c))))
```

Apply the group by and use the created `exprs`:

```
val df2 = df.groupBy(col(cols.head)).agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail:_*)
  .select(col(cols.head), map(cols.tail.flatMap(c => Seq(col(c), col(s"sum($c)"))):_*).as("map"))
```

Above an extra `select` is required to create the `map` and the `cols.tail.flatMap(c => Seq(col(c), col(s"sum($c)"))` is simply a list of the new columns that should be added to the `map`.

Resulting output is identical to before:

```
+---+---------------------+
|key|map                  |
+---+---------------------+
|b  |Map(v1 -> 1, v2 -> 0)|
|a  |Map(v1 -> 2, v2 -> 1)|
+---+---------------------+
```

Comment: Aha! So `Array:_*` turns the array into a set of parameters. I wonder why Spark disallows `.agg(exprs:_*)` though. This helps greatly - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out how to produce the result of my wanted answer based from @Shaido's answer.

```
def create_sum_map(cols: Array[String]): Column = 
  map(cols.flatMap(c => Seq(lit(c), sum(col(c)))):_*)

df.groupBy(col(cols.head)).agg(create_sum_map(columnNames) as "map")
```

I assume this works because a `sum(Column)` with affected columns is present within `create_sum_map()` in the `.agg()` function.