# Spark dataframe reducebykey like operation

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe with the following data (I use spark-csv to load the data in):

```
key,value
1,10
2,12
3,0
1,20
```

is there anything similar to spark RDD `reduceByKey` which can return a Spark DataFrame as: (basically, summing up for the same key values)

```
key,value
1,30
2,12
3,0
```

(I can transform the data to RDD and do a `reduceByKey` operation, but is there a more Spark DataFrame API way to do this?)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you don't care about column names you can use `groupBy` followed by `sum`:

```
df.groupBy($"key").sum("value")
```

otherwise it is better to replace `sum` with `agg`:

```
df.groupBy($"key").agg(sum($"value").alias("value"))
```

Finally you can use raw SQL:

```
df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT key, SUM(value) AS value FROM df GROUP BY key")
```

See also [DataFrame / Dataset groupBy behaviour/optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32902982/6910411)

Comment: In the RDD API, I use `reduceByKey` since `groupByKey` collects all values for a key into memory - if a key is associated to many values, a worker could run out of memory. Does `groupBy` have that limitation too?

Comment: @jeffreyveon http://stackoverflow.com/q/32902982/1560062 but a) there is more than one mechanism of actual groupBy in Spark b) if aggregate like operations it is still possible to get OOMs for different reasons.

Comment: Could you comment further on "If you don't care about column names..." What happens to the column names in this case, exactly?

Comment: @justanotherbrain The cloumn name would be something in the lines of _c1, _c2 etc., instead of "value" - the case when you use "alias".

Answer (score 2):

I think user goks missed out on some part in the code. Its not a tested code.

.map should have been used to convert the rdd to a pairRDD using .map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey. ....

reduceByKey is not available on a single value rdd or regular rdd but pairRDD.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I agree this still converts to rdd then to dataframe.

```
df.select('key','value').map(lambda x: x).reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b).toDF(['key','value'])
```

Comment: why is `.map(lambda x: x)` necessary?