# Count and groubpy equivalent in pyspark

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, transform

I am new to Spark and I am trying to apply `groupby` and `count` to my dataframe `df` on the `users` attribute.

```
import pandas as pd

comments = [ (1, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
  (1, "Spark is awesome"),
  (2, None),
  (2, "And I don't know why..."),
  (3, "Blah blah")]

df  = pd.DataFrame(comments )
df.columns = ["users", "comments"]
```

Which looks like this is pandas

```
       users                 comments
0      1   Hi I heard about Spark
1      1         Spark is awesome
2      2                     None
3      2  And I don't know why
4      3                Blah blah
```

I want to find the equivalent of the following pandas code for pyspark

```
df.groupby(['users'])['users'].transform('count')
```

The output looks like this:

```
    0    2
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    1
dtype: int64
```

Could you help me how I can implement this in `PySpark`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in pyspark : `df.groupby('user').count()` . In pyspark `groupby()` is an alias for `groupBy()` [Pyspark docs are pretty easy reading with some good examples.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy)

**UPDATE:**

Now that I understand the request a little better, it doesn't appear that pyspark has inplace `transform` support yet. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464577/pandas-style-transform-of-grouped-data-on-pyspark-dataframe)

But you can do it via a join.

```
df2=df.groupby('users').count()
df.join(df2, df.users==df2.users, "left")\
    .drop(df2.users).drop(df.comments)

+-----+-----+
|users|count|
+-----+-----+
|    1|    2|
|    1|    2|
|    3|    1|
|    2|    2|
|    2|    2|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks @data_steve. I think my issue is in the `transform` part. I'd like to insert the counted values as a new column (or the `user` column) in the same dataframe. Anyway easy ways to do this?

Comment: @MomoPP usually you'd give a small data example to illustrate what you mean, both from where you are starting and what you want to output to look like. I'm a little confused by this wording in your post `replace it by the count values`. What does it refer to: the user column or the dataframe?

Comment: Thank you very much, Steve, for going out of your way and helping me out here. Sorry for not providing enough details on this problem before. It totally makes sense now. Excellent work.

Comment: @momopp We're all new at this. I found this resource helpful on how to construct better questions. But pyspark community here is thin compared to other groups. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask