# How to perform group and count using map and reduce function in Spark 2.3.1

Tags: java, apache-spark, mapreduce, dataset

I am a new bee to spark and I am trying to perform a group by and count using the following spark functions:

```
 Dataset<Row> result =  dataset
       .groupBy("column1", "column2")
       .count();
```

But I read [here](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) that using group by is not a good idea since it does not have a combiner, which in turn affects the spark job's runtime efficiency.
Instead, one should use reduceByKey function for aggregation operations.

So I tried using `reduceByKey` function, but it is not available for `dataset`. Instead, datasets use `reduce(ReduceFunction<Row> func)`.

Since I can not find an example to perform group and count with reduce function, I tried converting it to `JavaRDD` and used `reduceByKey`:

```
//map each row to 1 and then group them by key 
JavaPairRDD<String[], Integer> mapOnes;
            try {
                 mapOnes = dailySummary.javaRDD().mapToPair(
                        new PairFunction<Row, String[], Integer>() {
                            @Override
                            public Tuple2<String[], Integer> call(Row t) throws Exception {
                                return new Tuple2<String[], Integer>(new String[]{t.getAs("column1"), t.getAs("column2")}, 1);
                            }   
                });
            }catch(Exception e) {
                log.error("exception in mapping ones: "+e);
                throw new Exception();
            }


        JavaPairRDD<String[], Integer> rowCount;
        try {
            rowCount = mapOnes.reduceByKey(
                new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {

                    @Override
                    public Integer call(Integer v1, Integer v2) throws Exception {
                        return v1+v2;
                    }
                });
        }catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("exception in reduce by key: "+e);
            throw new Exception();
        }
```

But this is also giving exception as `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` for `mapToPair` function.

Can anyone suggest a better way to group and perform count using dataset's `reduce` and `map` function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If I can give you a tip, use SCALA. Java is not where it is at, except for may be KAFKA.

Comment: "But I read here that using group by is not a good idea since it does not have a combiner" - [DataFrame / Dataset groupBy behaviour/optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32902982/8371915)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The groupBy in the link you added refers to RDD. In the RDD semantics, groupBy would basically shuffle all the data according to the key, i.e. it would bring ALL values relating to the key to one place.

This is why reduceByKey is suggested as reduceByKey first performs the reduce operation on each partition and only the reduced value is shuffled which means a lot less traffic (and prevents out of memory issues with bringing everything to one partition).

In Datasets, groupBy behaves differently. It does not give  a dataset as a returned object but instead a KeyValueGroupedDataset object. When you do count on this object (or the more generic agg), it basically defines a reducer which works very similar to reduceByKey.

This means there is no need for a separate reduceByKey method (the dataset groupby is actually a form of reduceByKey).

Stick with the original groupBy(...).count(...)

Comment: but is there any other way to group rows which is more efficient than group by?

Comment: Depends on your need. For nearly all aggregations this would be the most efficient way. I would say that using dataframe semantics instead of dataset semantics can often improve performance. In your case through,you are using dataframe semantics behind the scenes as you are grouping by columns rather than by some mapping function.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a dataset containing 2 columns, one with the name of the county and the other the state in the US.

Desired output:

```
reduce()
Autauga County, Alabama, Baldwin County, Alabama, Barbour County, Alabama, Bibb County, Alabama, Blount County, Alabama, Bullock County, Alabama, Butler County, Alabama, Calhoun County, Alabama, Chambers County, Alabama, Cherokee County, Alabama, Chilton County,
…
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println("reduce()");
String listOfCountyStateDs = countyStateDs
    .reduce(
        new CountyStateConcatenatorUsingReduce());
System.out.println(listOfCountyStateDs);
```

Implementation:

```
 private final class CountyStateConcatenatorUsingReduce
      implements ReduceFunction<String> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 12859L;

    @Override
    public String call(String v1, String v2) throws Exception {
      return v1 + ", " + v2;
    }
  }
```

However, you will have to write your own logic, which may be time consuming and you'd prefer using the groupBy anyway...