# Is the ‘group by’ in the spark SQL optimized?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Does the data combine in each partition?
As we all know ,if use **reduceByKey** ,data is combined at each partition , only one output for one key at each partition to send over network. reduceByKey required combining all your values into another value with the exact same type.
I mean, is it like **reducebykey**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataFrame / Dataset groupBy behaviour/optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902982/dataframe-dataset-groupby-behaviour-optimization)

Comment: yes its optimized, but limited to the built-in aggregation functions (unless you implement an UDAF).