# How to replace groupBy with more efficient method

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce

My task is to analyze Kennedy Space Center logs using Apache Spark. The code is working but I want to get rid of `groupBy` operation because of it cost.

The code below collect list of requests with 5xx error code and count failed requests.

**My code**

```
SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName(application_name).getOrCreate();
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(session.sparkContext());
JavaRDD<LogEntry> input = jsc.textFile(hdfs_connect + args[0])
                .map(App::log_entry_extractor)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull);

Dataset<Row> dataSet = session.createDataFrame(input, LogEntry.class);

// task 1
dataSet.filter(col("returnCode").between(500, 599))
                .groupBy("request")
                .count()
                .select("request", "count")
//                .sort(desc("count"))
                .coalesce(1)
                .toJavaRDD()
                .saveAsTextFile(hdfs_connect + output_folder_task_1);
```

**Example of data**

```
199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245
unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3985
199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/mission-sts-73.html HTTP/1.0" 200 4085
burger.letters.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/liftoff.html HTTP/1.0" 304 0
199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/sts-73-patch-small.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 4179
burger.letters.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:12 -0400] "GET /images/NASA-logosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 304 0
burger.letters.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:12 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/video/livevideo.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 0
205.212.115.106 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:12 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/countdown.html HTTP/1.0" 200 3985
d104.aa.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:13 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3985
129.94.144.152 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:13 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 7074
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your desired output? What do you expect to get?

Comment: Code reads RDD, then converts it to DataFrame, and then back to RDD; such conversions can take some time. Fo example, just RDD can be used for all operations: extract key and then just "reduceByKey" used.

Comment: Oh my poor broken pretzel... how did we end up here with such an horrible pile of frameworks and convoluted code... You are literally wasting time and effort. In java, I would read lines and count in a variable (while writing to another files if that is desired). In linux you would grep. awk, wc (some neat oneliner sent over ssh.). This spark insanity is 10000 times too complicated for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with `groupBy` in this context - [DataFrame / Dataset groupBy behaviour/optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32902982) - nor there is really a viable alternative.

`coalesce(1)` from the other hand, is most of the time an anti-pattern, which in the worst case scenario can [turn your process into a sequential one](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#coalesce-int-)

> However, if you're doing a drastic coalesce, e.g. to numPartitions = 1, this may result in your computation taking place on fewer nodes than you like (e.g. one node in the case of numPartitions = 1). To avoid this, you can call repartition. This will add a shuffle step, but means the current upstream partitions will be executed in parallel (per whatever the current partitioning is).

Consider replacing it with `repartition(1)` or removing whatsoever